# Process of making a huge txt into array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I got thousands of sentences on a txt file, and my first Android application should take one from there and put it on a textView.

I could put the txt file as a resource, or also, try to get all the sentences and convert it to an array. I don't want to put my txt into the application, but directly the array with the sentences. How could I automatically "translate" thousands of sentences to an array-like list?

Comment: Will the text ever change, or will it be static? If it is static (and you don't want to use resources), why not store it as a `static final String` variable or something and just use that?

Comment: Sentences won't change. It just shows them as a 'quote'. I would like to know if there is a way to translate all of them to an array. I mean, I'm not able to re-type every quote as an array, putting " ", all the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i guess this is what u dont want to do...
//InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.list);
```

so get a InputStream object and use following code

```
List<String> content=new ArrayList<String>();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
linereader = new LineNumberReader(isr);
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {  // num is  total no of lines in file
    try {
            line = linereader.readLine();
            content.add(line);

         } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
        e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }// for ends
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel... this is a one-liner:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

List<String> sentences = (List<String>)IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream("filename.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that each item only has one period, you split on that. If you can't do that but can use newlines, use that.

```
final String blob = "Quote 1. Quote2. Quote '3'.";
String[] quotes = blob.split('\\.');
> ["Quote 1", "Quote2", "Quote '3'"];

OR


final String blob = "Quote 1.\nQuote 2 longer.";
String[] quotes = blob.split("\n");
> ["Quote 1.", "Quote 2 longer."]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to put the text file in your resources folder and then read it using a BufferedReader.

Depending on the contents of your text file, you could read the text line by line and add it to an array as you go, or you could just read the entire file as a string and use .split(), which would return an array of strings for you to use.